Fire base cloud messagin not receiveing notifications on web
I am working on a Firebase push notification functionality on Laravel Vue project. I was able to send the notifications from laravel successfully but was not able to receive them on client side.
When I trigger push notification from laravel I get a successful response as below
{"message":"Push notification sent successfully!!","response":{"name":"projects\/paseo-307906\/messages\/3877998254258475769"}}

The Related function is
    public function sendPushNotification()
{
    try {
        // Initialize Firebase Messaging with the service account credentials
        $firebase = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(base_path('google/firebase_credentials.json'));
        $messaging = $firebase->createMessaging();

        $message = CloudMessage::fromArray([
            'notification' => [
                'title' => 'Hello from Firebase!',
                'body' => 'This is a test notification.'
            ],
            'topic' => 'global'
        ]);

        // Send the message
        $response = $messaging->send($message);

        // Optionally, you can log the response or process it as needed
        // $response will contain information about the sent message

        // Return a success response
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Push notification sent successfully!!', 'response' => $response]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Handle the exception and return an error response
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Failed to send push notification', 'details' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
    }
}

For now I am setting the 'topic' => 'global' to test the functionality.
But I don't receive any notification on the client side (vue js)
Here is the related code on vue js side
The content of firebase-messaging-sw.js file placed in root folder
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.7/firebase-app.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.7/firebase-messaging.js')

const firebaseConfig = {
--configs here--
};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

The content of firebase.js file
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firebase-messaging'

const firebaseConfig = {
 --Cofigs here---
};

// Initialize Firebase


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export default firebase.messaging()

This file is imported in app.js and as below
import firebaseMessaging from './firebase'
Vue.prototype.$messaging = firebaseMessaging

As now the messaging can be used globally, I am using it in my vue component as below
In the mounted hook a am calling
this.notificationPermission(this.$messaging);

In the methods
notificationPermission(messaging){
                try{
                    
                    Notification.requestPermission().then(permission => {
                        if (permission === "granted") {
                            messaging.getToken( { vapidKey: process.env.MIX_FIREBASE_VAPID_KEY }).then((currentToken) => {
                                if (currentToken) {
                                    console.log('client token', currentToken);
                                    messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
                                        console.log('Message received. ', payload);
                                        const noteTitle = payload.notification.title;
                                        const noteOptions = {
                                            body: payload.notification.body,
                                            icon: payload.notification.icon,
                                        };
                                        new Notification(noteTitle, noteOptions);
                                    });
                                    this.saveFCMToken(currentToken);
                                } else {
                                    console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
                                }
                                }).catch((err) => {
                                console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
                            });

                        } else {
                            console.log("Unable to get permission to notify.");
                        }
                    });
                }catch(e){
                    console.log('the notificationPermission error is ', e);
                }
                
            },
            saveFCMToken(token){
                try{
                    var apiUrl = this.baseUrl + 'api/save-fpm-token';
                    axios.post(apiUrl,{
                        user_id: this.user_id,
                        fcm_token: token,
                        device_type:'web'
                    },{headers: this.headers}).then(res => {
                        if(res.data.status === true){
                            console.log(the user toke aginst id ${this.user_id} was saved successfully);
                        }else{
                            console.log('could not save user token due to',res.data.message);
                        }
                    });
                }catch(e){
                    console.log('save token exception is ', e);
                }
            },

From the console output I can see the token is generated and saved in database correctly, but I never see the console.log('Message received. ', payload); or the browser notification message when I send the notification from laravel end.
